# SQL Server Reporting Services LocalDB doesn't exist error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I've been trying to view deployed reports in SSRS using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014, but this is the error message I've been receiving:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist. )

This is what my connection string looks like:

> Data Source=(localdb)\VIRAJ-PC;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012

I've done numerous things to troubleshoot this problem including editing the firewall settings to open ports 1433 and 1434 that need to be accessed, made sure that the MSSQLSERVER service was running, configured the local server to allow incoming connections, have turned on TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols through the configuration manager, and have checked to see if the LocalDB instance is running through sqllocaldb.exe in the command line (it is running).

If it matters at all, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2016. I don't want to have to do an uninstall as I've done so two or three times already because of previous errors and have gone through a lot of configuration so if there's a way to fix this without having to just reinstall, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you get this error during the deploy process, or after the deploy succeeds when running the report? Is the SSRS service local, or remote?

Comment: After the deploy succeeds and when running the report. The SSRS service is local.

Comment: Are you sure the the database is on the (localdb) instance? Or, do you have a full version of SQL Server installed, and the database is there? It seems odd that adventure works would be on (localdb).

Comment: Yep, AdventureWorks is on (localdb), I attached it to the instance manually. Do you think putting AdventureWorks under a different instance would possibly help things or no?

Comment: I can't say for sure, it may be worth a try. It is strange that SSRS can't seem to find (localdb). Then again, there may limitations with (localdb) that are keeping that from happening.